Avoid warning in minimum alignment declaration
I'm trying to use the always-zero bits in pointers for a bool value. Here's an example of the code:
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
struct alignas(2) Node {
    T elememt;
    Node* next;
};

int main() {
    Node<char> n;
    auto addr = reinterpret_cast<std::size_t>(&n);
    assert((addr & 1) == 0);
}

However, when compiling this code with MSVC, I get the following warning:

warning C4359: 'Node': Alignment specifier is less than actual
alignment (8), and will be ignored.


I understand that pointers on most platforms (including MSVC) are aligned to at least 8 bytes, so the alignas(2) here is redundant in terms of actual memory layout. However, for semantic clarity, I want to explicitly specify the alignment to indicate how I intend to use the least-significant bit.
Is there a way to avoid this warning in MSVC while keeping the alignas specifier for semantic clarity? Or is there a better approach to achieve this goal?

Yes, you can disable any specific warning in a particular range of code.  I would consider this link a duplicate of your question.

You can define the next member variable as std::array<std::byte, sizeof Node*> raw_next; and then std::memcpy into and out of raw_next the Node* value.

"always-zero bits in pointers" is a wrong assumption. char a[2]; std::cout << static_cast<void*>(&a[1]); outputs an address with the least-significant bit set up.

@3CxEZiVlQ, but if the items in the array are aligned 2 like here, their addresses will always be even. But on some processors the lowest bit may be used. For example, the ARM set the lowest bit of pointers to instructions (always at an even address) to define the processor language as Thumb from this instruction.
